# Asynchronously sending Emails in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, smtpclient

```
Public Async Function SendEmail(ByVal EmailToIds As String, ByVal Subject As String, ByVal Message As String, Optional ByVal EmailCcIds As String = "", Optional ByVal MailAttachment As String = "", Optional ByVal FromEmailType As Integer = 0, Optional EmailBccIds As String = "") As Task
    Dim EmailPwd() As String
    Dim FromEmail, Password As String
    'Dim objSmtp As SmtpClient
    Dim objMail As MailMessage
    Dim objAttachment As Attachment
    Try
        EmailPwd = GetEmailPassword(FromEmailType).Split("|")
        FromEmail = EmailPwd(0)
        Password = EmailPwd(1)
        objMail = New MailMessage
        objMail.From = New MailAddress(FromEmail)
        objMail.Subject = Subject
        objMail.IsBodyHtml = True
        objMail.Body = Message
        objMail.To.Add(EmailToIds)
        If Len(EmailCcIds) > 0 Then
            objMail.CC.Add(EmailCcIds)
        End If
        If Len(EmailBccIds) > 0 Then
            objMail.Bcc.Add(EmailBccIds)
        End If
        If MailAttachment <> "" Then
            objAttachment = New Attachment(MailAttachment)
            objMail.Attachments.Add(objAttachment)
        End If

        Using objSmtp = New SmtpClient()
            objSmtp.Host = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("SmtpClient")
            objSmtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            objSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            objSmtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(FromEmail, Password)
            objSmtp.Port = 587
            objSmtp.EnableSsl = True
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s As Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) True
            Await objSmtp.SendMailAsync(objMail)
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw Ex
    End Try
End Function
```

Getting Error : Failure sending mail.

Please help me to do this.

Thank You So much in Advance.

Comment: This site provides a preview of your post for a reason. Don't submit if your code looks like a dog's breakfast. Don't expect others to help you if you can't help them by providing readable code.

Comment: As for the issue, you are specifically asking about sending the message asynchronously. Have you tried the equivalent synchronous code to see whether it actually is an issue with the async call? If you haven't, you should. If it's not then that's a red herring that just makes it harder for us to identify the issue. You need to do ALOL that you can BEFORE posting a question here, which includes full debugging to make sure that every line of code and every bit of data is and does what you expect.

Comment: On the subject of doing all you can, have you read the documentation for the `EnableSsl` property? It contains some information that may well be relevant to this issue.

Comment: thnx you so much. I found the solution.